# Why IE doesn't update js file

Tags: javascript, tomcat, caching, reload

I am using tomcat6 and IE to show my page, I modified my javascript file, even if I tried to restart tomcat, use Ctrl+F5 on IE, use `psi.js?1500`, and so son, but IE still use old javascript file, though I can view there is new javascript on tomcat server `C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.53\wtpwebapps\local\myjs\js`, what can I do?

Comment: can you view source and see if the code is updated?

Comment: code is updated but IE F12 debug console not updated.